# Cloudformation lambda function code reference a generated s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Thanks in advance!

So I currently have a cloud formation script that creates a lambda function, the code in the lambda function needs to reference an s3 bucket that also needs to be generated by the same cloudformation script. The code for the lambda function is stored in a pre-cloudformation bucket which is pulled in when it is ran.

The problem I have is how would I cater for a programatically generated bucket name in my node.js lambda function code??

Feels a bit of a chicken and egg situation to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reference your S3 bucket by using a [Lambda function environment variable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html). Your code is static and does not reference a hard-coded bucket by name. Instead, it retrieves the bucket name from the environment variable.

In your CloudFormation script, you would set the environment variable as part of your [AWS::Lambda::Function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html) definition under the `environment` property.

For example:

```
"Resources" : {

    "MyFunction" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Lambda::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Environment" : {
          "Variables" : {
            "BucketName" : { "Ref" : "MyBucket" }
          }
        },
      }
    },
    "MyBucket" : {
       "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds promising thanks, I will give this a go! So essentially the code in my nodejs script will reference the environment variable bucket name instead of the actual bucket name, is that correct?

Comment: Correct. The environment variable will contain the value of the actual bucket name.